# How to create 7" Tablet (1280 * 800) Screen Resolution Emulator in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to test my application on Android Springboard tablet.

http://www.slashgear.com/t-mobile-springboard-tablet-review-07193734/

I need to create emulator for 1280 * 800 screen resolution and 7" Tablet for android 3.0 / 3.1 or above...

When i create emulator for 1280 * 800 screen resolution its consider by default 10" tablet..

Any one please suggest me how to create for specified screen and specified 7" tablet...

Thanks

Comment: While clicking on "start" emulator, there is a option to mention "Screen size(inch)"

Comment: Yes but its scale original emulator .. like 10" tablet scale with 7"..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify

> Abstracted LCD Density

So, if you have same number of pixels with more screen density, it's got to be a smaller screen.

The formula is:

> DENSITY = sqrt (x^2+y^2)/d where d is the diagonal in inches.

So, supposing you want a d=7", then you need a density of:

> Density=sqrt(1280x1280+800*800)/7 = 215'6339

So, fix the ABSTRACTED LCD DENSITY to 216 and there you are.

Comment: thnaks @ArcDare .its very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue ..But with android 4.1 we can create an AVD that has option WXGA800-7in (1280x800, high density, large screen) :
Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you create new emulator, take a look at Screen Resolution Field in the dialog box. Set your desired resolution. Now before starting the emulator Check  and specify size..
Hope this helped you.

**Edit**
Take a look at snap shot..[image]

Comment: Yes , i know but its create 10" tablet simulator.... i need 7" tablet and 1280 * 800 Screen resolution.........

Comment: dear I have just created 7" tablet with 1280*800 resolution with same specified method above...
I am not getting why aren't you able to do so..:S

Comment: Thanks, but these way created 10" tablet simulator and you run as scale with 7" tablet... but its actually its 10" tablet. its show 7" tablet but show after scale.. i need to create 7" tablet without scale.