# Android SDK for Eclipse - How to add 4.3 inch screen preview

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to add somehow a 4.3 inch screen preview for the layout? Right now the closest options are for 4.0" and for 4.65", and I want for 4.3"

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908597/android-emulator-htc-sensation-xl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVD provides the option to create custom Device, which is then listed in the preview section.

You can create Custom sized device by opening the AVD.
1. Select "Device Definitions"
2. Create Your custom device.

[image]

Now you can check the preview section. You will have 4.3" created custom preview.